# Spring vault authentication token renewal

Tags: java, spring, backend, vault

I am writing a microservice that stores and fetches secrets from vault.
In order to do so, I need to refresh my authentication token, so I am using `spring.cloud.vault.config.lifecycle.enabled=true`.

The problem is, that when I set this to `true`, it seems like `spring vault` also refreshes all my leases (configurations that I used at the start up of the microservice).

Why is the same flag used to configure both the renewal of the authentication token and the secret leases?
Is there some way to get around it, other than setting the min-renewal to be very large? (hence avoiding too many unnecessary leases renewals)